# What does a space mean in a resistor value on a schematic?

Tags: resistors

Some resistors in this schematic are clear (i.e. 47K = 47K) but i'm not sure what "4 7K" means. Does it also mean 47K? or is it 4.7K?

[image]

*Source: https://fccid.io/XMR202005BG95M5/User-Manual/Users-Manual-4826952.pdf pg 53*

Comment: As there are 47K resistors shown, it is highly likely that the value in question is 4K7

Comment: Do you know where the diagram came from?  Is it a portion of a larger part?

Comment: Another wild guess is that the circuit had been initially drawn with 4.7K/47K voltage divider for base biasing. When the designer discovered that the high base current with this divider deteriorates the switching speed on returning from saturation to cutoff, they decided to increase the upper resistance. For some reason they chose to simply erase the decimal point in the typed 4.7K resistance value of the schematic image rather than edit the schematic data. This crazy idea might become more realistic had the NM designation happened to stand for Not Mounted.

Comment: You've posted a PNG file, but is that how you received it, or did you convert it from a PDF? Disappearing characters in PDFs aren't exactly unknown

Comment: sdolan - Hi, Please note the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that if a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, for online material, the source webpage or PDF etc. should be named & linked (see that rule regarding references for books / articles etc.). Therefore please [edit] your question to include the original source link for that image (and please remember it's your responsibility to do that in future). Thanks. (Please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules.)

Comment: i have edited to provide the source and page number of the pdf showing the rendering problem.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> What does a space mean in a resistor value on a schematic?

In *this* case, it definitely means that there was originally a decimal point in that space, but somehow between the original image and the one you have, the decimal point was lost.

This is confirmed because I found the original schematic (which seems to be in some product manuals from Quectel) - see below, where the decimal points are clearly visible. I added red rings around the resistors where the decimal points are missing in the image you included:

[image: Quectel - Level-Translation Reference Circuit with Dual-Transistor Circuit (Recommended for GNSS UART)]

Here is a zoomed-in extract showing the decimal point on the left-hand resistor which is ringed in the above image:

[image: zoomed-in extract of circuit]

Images from:
[FCC - Quectel BG95 Series Hardware Design, LPWA Module Series, Rev. BG95_Series_Hardware_Design_V1.2](https://fcc.report/FCC-ID/XMR202010BG95M3/5130779.pdf)
*Figure 19: Reference Circuit with Dual-Transistor Circuit (Recommended for GNSS UART)*

Comment: This usually happens because the software rendering the PDF can't find the font originally used and doesn't know how to substitute it. Happens more with cross-platform use.

Comment: And this is why it's better to use `4K7` rather than `4.7K`!

Comment: @barbecue and also when created on systems using a different character set to the reader

Comment: Nice find. This is the exact schematic i was referencing. The PDF you have attached works and shows the decimal place. I was looking at it from a different website in chrome browser and the decimal place is missing: https://fccid.io/XMR202005BG95M5/User-Manual/Users-Manual-4826952.pdf

Comment: @sdolan that makes it clear - the problem is the source of the PDF.  Compared to the original Quectel link SamGibson found, all the graphics have been rasterised in your copy, so the text in the circuit diagrams is not longer text.  It's not scanned, because the body text is OK, but strangely  the blacks aren't fully black. In the absence of any evidence that this isn't a one-off, I'd avoid that site as a source of datasheets, and go direct to the manufacturer.  That's not a guarantee of perfection, but will give you the lowest chance of errors

Comment: ... They may have recompressed the file in an attempt to reduce the file size, but if so they've done it wrong - the reduction is <10%, and vector graphics are normally more efficient to store than raster

Answer (score 17):

It's anyone's guess.

If it were a scan of a schematic I would say that the decimal point had been lost. Since it looks like a screen-grab of a CAD drawing that is unlikely.

To avoid this sort of confusion (with missing decimal points) it is normal to use 4k7 (small 'k' for kilo) to signify the multiplier and the decimal position. You might also see 4R7 for a 4.7 Ω value as there is no multiplier (so 4R7, 47R, 470R, 4k7, 47k, etc.).

Comment: The standard for ["RKM"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RKM_code) code actually prefers uppercase.  IEC-60062-2016 section 4.2.1.1: "the letters L, R, K, M and G are consistently written as capital letters in this coding, regardless of the convention for SI prefixes using a lower-case k as the decimal multiplier for 10^3, kilo."

Comment: It probably dates back to when draftsmen used stencils and repedograph pens on Mylar film. The stencils probably only had upper-case letters.

Comment: It is possible that a screen grab has lost the decimal point due to several reasons, actually...

Comment: Even without stencils, in the 1980s I was taught that all lettering on technical drawings should be upper case.

Answer (score 11):

It looks like a decimal point got dropped from "4.7K".  First because there's a space there, in two spots.  Second, because that makes for a 1:10 ratio between the series resistor and the shunt resistor driving the transistor bases, and that's a pretty common ratio when you're using transistors as inverters.